# Intelligent solution to computing jump addresses in a bytecode compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, bytecode

Let's say I'm implementing a bytecode compiler, similar to Lua's/Python's... so on.

I'm traversing the AST, generating bytecode instructions, and I run into a `break` inside of an `if-else` inside of a `while` loop:

```
while (cond1)
    if (cond2)
        ...
    else
        break
```

(I tried writing out equivalent bytecode but it didn't look too helpful.)

The point is, there are at least 4 "jump" instructions in that example, and I
want to find an elegant solution to filling in the jump addresses as I compile the AST...
I don't know the jump address for the `while` loop or the `break` until after I've fully
"compiled" the inner statements.

1. A pseudocode solution would be ideal
2. A solution shouldn't depend on whether I'm implementing a register- or stack-based bytecode compiler (I'm playing with both)

I'm not reading the dragon book just yet.

If I'm recursively compiling the AST, when I reach a `break` statement inside of some arbitrary number of loops and `if-else` blocks, how should the compiler know which empty label to jump to? I'm guessing some type of label-name stack external to the recursive AST walking function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The principle you need is called "backpatching": fill in a dummy value for the forward jump, generate the code for the body of the statement, and then go back and replace the dummy value with the real one at the end.

e.g.

```
# start of codegen for 'while'
L1:
  [evaluate cond1]
  jne L2   # forward reference: use a dummy value for now

# start of codegen for 'if ... else'
L3:
  [evaluate cond2]
  jne L4   # another forward reference: use a dummy value for now
  [code in 'if' branch]
  j L5     # another forward reference: use a dummy value for now
L4:
  [code in 'else' branch before 'break']
  j L2
  [code in 'else' branch after 'break']
L5:   # end of 'if ... else'
  # now go back and fill in references to L4, L5 inside the 'if ... else' block
  # end of codegen for 'if ... else'

  # codegen for 'while' continues...
  j L1   # loop
L2:   # end of 'while' loop
  # now go back and fill in references to L2 inside the 'while' block
  # end of codegen for 'while'
```

---

Regarding your edit:

> If I'm recursively compiling the AST, when I reach a `break` statement inside of some arbitrary number of loops and `if-else` blocks, how should the compiler know which empty label to jump to? I'm guessing some type of label-name stack external to the recursive AST walking function.

The target of the jump which implements the `break` statement is the end of the innermost enclosing loop; yes, you could track that with an explicit external stack.

But, if you have a recursive AST walking function, you already have an *implicit* stack - the call frames of the recursive function invocations - so you probably don't need an explicit one as well.

e.g. in

```
...
while (outer)
    ...
    if (outer_done)
        break
    ...

    while (inner)
        ...
        if (inner_done)
            break
        ...
    [break from inner 'while' ends up here]

    ...
    if (outer_done_2)
        break
    ...
[break from outer 'while' ends up here]
...
```

the entirety of the code generation for the inner `while` loop happens within a recursive walk of the AST for the body of the outer `while` loop.  Inside this recursive call, you only need to care about the inner loop, not the outer one.

So, all you need to do is:

- save any current backpatching state at the start of processing a `while`
- start a new empty list for tracking any `break` that appears within the body of this `while`
- handle the body (which may result in a recursive call)
- apply the backpatches
- then restore the previous state before exiting.

e.g. something a bit like this:

```
codegen for while:
    save previous break backpatch list
    initialise break backpatch list as empty
    perform codegen for evaluating condition
    perform codegen for body statements
    apply backpatches
    restore previous break backpatch list
```

The current `break` backpatch list must be part of some state which is passed to all the codegen functions (the codegen for `break` needs to append to it).  But the saved list could just be tracked as a local variable of the `while` codegen function.

Comment: The break inside the else block should be a `j L2`. When recursively traversing AST nodes, the break needs to be converted to the correct label.

Comment: this is really helpful, but I've pretty much gotten this far. I came across the 'backpatching' terminology on a [NYU CS class page](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring09/G22.2130-001/lectures/lecture-12.html), but unfortunately it didn't go into much detail. I added a tiny bit more to my question to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: Great, that makes sense. Any `break` or `continue` statements only apply to the current enclosing loop construct of course. I just need to pass some state-structure recursively as well. Thanks for your help.