# How to parse If-Else brackets

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, if-statement

In my C like Programming language I want the compiler to parse If-Else brackets. I have some code like:

```
if( varA == varB ) {
  if ( varB == varC ) {
   varA = 1;
  } else {
   varB = 1;
  }
};
```

and want it to parse to this (fictional assembler):

```
compare varA with varB
jump if equal to condition_2
jump to else_condition2  ; gets only executed if statement above does not get executed -> else

label condition_2:
compare varB with varC
jump if equal to if_bracket_1
jump to else_bracket_1

label if_bracket_1:
varA = 1;
jump to back_label

label else_bracket_1:
varB = 1;
jump to back_label 

label else_condition2: 
; nothing, because there is no else

label back_label:
nop ; continue main program here
```

I know how to parse the conditions to jump-if-equal and so on, and I know the parsing method will be recursive .. but I do not have a clue how to implement this parsing method .. I do not need code, just an idea, how to manage this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know how to write a parser that does not output any code but just parses the input?

Comment: What you describe isn't parsing at all. It is code generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are asking. From what I understand you either have some problems parsing the source or generating the code.

For the parsing part you can easily use the [recursive descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) technique if you want to write it by hand. Basically you write functions that parse each of your syntactical classes--e.g. expressions, blocks, statements like if, while and for. The you have them call each other recursively. Usually the parser functions return AST nodes, and the caller composes them in a bigger node.

In your example you would have a function for parsing logical expressions, if statements, blocks of expressions/statements and if statements. When you see the `if` in your token stream you know that an if statement follows so you call the appropriate parsing function, say `parse_if`. Thanks to the grammar `parse_if` knows that and `if` statement should look like `if (<logical expression>) <block> [else <block>]`--square brackets denote an optional block, angled ones mandatory. So you first recursively call the function for parsing logical expressions, say `parse_logical_exp`. This will return the AST node for the logical expression of the if statement which you can later plug into the final AST. The same for the then block. If, after you're done with the then block, you encounter an `else` in the token stream, you call the block parsing function again. If none of the sub-functions signaled an error you're good so you can finally build your AST for the if statement and return it to your caller. In (Python) pseudocode:

```python
def parse_if(tokens):
    # Skip over the if token or signal an error if the current token is not an "if"
    tokens.expect("if")
    logical_condition = parse_logical_exp(tokens)
    if logical_condition is Error:
        raise ParseError(logical_condition.message)
    then_block = parse_block(tokens)
    if then_block is Error:
        raise ParseError(then_block.message)
    else_block = None
    if tokens.current() == "else":
        # Skip over the else token or signal an error
        tokens.expect("else")
        else_block = parse_block(tokens)
        if else_block is Error:
            raise ParseError(else_block.message)
    return IfNode(logical_condition, then_block, else_block)
```

Note that this is just some pseudocode and you might want to do error checking/reporting in a different way.

The problem you might be referring to is called the ["dangling else problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else). Basically you can't tell to which if an else belongs. To quote from the wikipedia article:

> The convention when dealing with the dangling else is to attach the else to the nearby if statement, allowing for unambiguous context-free grammars, in particular. Programming languages like Pascal and C follow this convention, so there is no ambiguity in the semantics of the language

For the code generating part you might be interested in the response to this question: [Intelligent solution to computing jump addresses in a bytecode compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094001/intelligent-solution-to-computing-jump-addresses-in-a-bytecode-compiler).